# Why is my paragraph not aligning correctly with my image?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to code a portfolio for myself and I'm having trouble with lining up my blog post image preview with the description preview. Here is an example image of how it looks on my computer:

[image: Example of my alignment problem]

Here is the HTML and CSS code I have written for this part of my website:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Beginning of "Recent Entries" blog posts -->
<div class="offset-by-one">

   <!-- Beginning of "Recent Entries" title -->
   <div class="recent">

      <h2 class="recent">Recent Entries</h2>

   </div>
   <!-- End of "Recent Entries" title -->

   <hr>

   <!-- Beginning of first blog post preview -->
   <div class="first-post">

       <!-- Beginning of first blog post date -->
       <div class="date">21 JUL 2013</div><br />
       <!-- End of first blog post date -->

       <!-- Beginning of first blog post picture -->
       <img src="./images/post1.png">
       <!-- End of first blog post picture -->

       <!-- Beginning of first blog post description -->
       <div class="offset-by-four">

          <p class="blog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a nunc eu mauris luctus tristique a a urna. Aliquam accumsan a quam id vehicula. Donec mattis justo purus, at congue ligula rhoncus nec. Duis vulputate nisl ac massa iaculis, at faucibus nunc mattis. Aliquam sit amet eros arcu. Aliquam accumsan a quam id vehicula. Donec mattis justo purus...</p>

          <!-- Beginning of first blog post "Read more" link -->
          <div class="offset-by-nine">

              <a class="read-more" href="#">Read more...</a>

          </div>
          <!-- End of first blog post "Read more" link -->

   </div>
   <!-- End of first blog post description -->

 </div>
 <!-- End of first blog post preview -->

</div>
<!-- End of "Recent Entries" blog posts -->
```

**CSS:**

```
/* "Recent Entries" section */
h2.recent {
    padding: 75px 0 0 0;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    color: #DD4422;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.date {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #9D9D9D;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.blog img {
    border: 3px solid #D5D5D5;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

h1.blog-title {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    color: #0094AA;
}

p.blog {
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    line-height: 180%;
}

a.read-more {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0094AA;
}
```

If it would make it easier on whoever is trying to figure out this problem to see the actual webpage, I'll post a link to it on first request.

Thanks for the help, guys!

**EDIT:**

Also, here is an image of what I would like it to look like:

[image: Example of how I'd like it]

Comment: Like you said, would be easier to see a fiddle or a live demo.

Comment: Do you want the text to be below the image or to the right to it?

Comment: @Morad I attached an example image of how I'd like it too look in my post.

Comment: @SimplyJordanNET there are a few ways to fix this. Most easily you can apply a negative margin-top to your paragraph, -101px to be specific. Another way is to use float:left and set widths to image and paragraph accordingly.

Comment: @Godinall I would rather go the "float: left;" route, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `float: left` to the css style of the image

Comment: This didn't fix the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: You have a problem with your style sheet... the class of the paragraph is blog. the image is not inside blog

Comment: Is this put under ".blog img"?

Comment: This wont work, because img is not under blog... add a class to your img element and change it in the css

Comment: Hmm.. There seems to be another problem. The title to the blog post is actually aligned with the image and not the date. I may have incorrectly said I wanted it aligned with the image when really I want it aligned with the date. Can you help with this?

Comment: Put the date and the image inside a div with class "left" for example and then add float:left to the style of this div instead for the image

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you very much. I know this next question isn't based on the topic of this thread, but I'd appreciate it if you could answer it for me. If you visit the page again, you'll notice the footer I added. The thing about it is it's not 100% across the page. I know if I take it out of the Primary Page DIV class it'll fix that, but if I do that the copyright text isn't responsive anymore. Do you have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
.first-post img, .second-post img { float:left;  margin-top: 35px; }
.offset-by-four h1 { line-height: auto;}
```

**HTML:**

remove `<br/>` after date div

Comment: This didn't fix the problem, unfortunately.